# How to extract the Freezing Index from Accelerometer data for FoG detecting?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, feature-extraction

I'm working on a project to detect Freezing of Gait episodes for Parkinson's Disease patients, and according to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.03428.pdf) and other ones, extracting the freezing index which is "**The power in the “freeze” band (3-
8Hz) divided by the power in the locomotor band (0.5-3Hz)**" will be a good feature.

Here is the explanation: **One standard feature which is extracted from the raw signals is the Freezing Index (FI), defined as the ratio between the power contained in the so-called freezing and locomotion frequency bands (3-8 Hz and 0.5-3 Hz respectively). This feature is convenient since it requires only FFT-computation.**

But I cannot how to implement it in Python.

I have a dataframe like this: 
[image]
Then I did something like this to extract features from the sensors time-series data:

```
win_size=200
step_size=40
for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'Label':
        df[col + '_avg'] = df[col].rolling(win_size).mean()[step_size - 1::step_size]
```

Now, I would like to extract the Freezing Index, How can I do this? and I need to someone to explain it to me because I don't fully understand it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article](https://raphaelvallat.com/bandpower.html) is very useful. There is a function in this article that computes the average power of the signal in a specific frequency band. And since the Freezing Index is the ratio between the power contained in the so-called freezing and locomotion frequency bands (3-8 Hz and 0.5-3 Hz respectively), we can use this function to get the power in each frequency band and divide them.

Here is the function:

```
def bandpower(data, sf, band, window_sec=None, relative=False):
    """Compute the average power of the signal x in a specific frequency band.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : 1d-array
        Input signal in the time-domain.
    sf : float
        Sampling frequency of the data.
    band : list
        Lower and upper frequencies of the band of interest.
    window_sec : float
        Length of each window in seconds.
        If None, window_sec = (1 / min(band)) * 2
    relative : boolean
        If True, return the relative power (= divided by the total power of the signal).
        If False (default), return the absolute power.

    Return
    ------
    bp : float
        Absolute or relative band power.
    """
    from scipy.signal import welch
    from scipy.integrate import simps
    band = np.asarray(band)
    low, high = band

    # Define window length
    if window_sec is not None:
        nperseg = window_sec * sf
    else:
        nperseg = (2 / low) * sf

    # Compute the modified periodogram (Welch)
    freqs, psd = welch(data, sf, nperseg=nperseg)

    # Frequency resolution
    freq_res = freqs[1] - freqs[0]

    # Find closest indices of band in frequency vector
    idx_band = np.logical_and(freqs >= low, freqs <= high)

    # Integral approximation of the spectrum using Simpson's rule.
    bp = simps(psd[idx_band], dx=freq_res)

    if relative:
        bp /= simps(psd, dx=freq_res)
    return bp
```

Then, I created this simple function to return the FI:

```
def freeze_index(data, sf, band1, band2, win_sec=None, relative=False):
    fi = bandpower(data, sf, band1, win_sec, relative) / bandpower(data, sf, band2, win_sec, relative)
    return fi
```

And here is how I called it in the rolling window function:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'Label':
        df[col + '_fi'] = df[col].rolling(win_size).apply(freeze_index, args=(fs, [3, 8], [0.5, 3], win_size,))[step_size - 1::step_size]
```

I hope it's the right solution, and I wish it helps.